# Laravel auth config of another guard doesnt works and stills using default model

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, controller

For context, I am making a application, where I have a User for the desktop application, and a Student user. I want to make API login using the Student and web auth with the default User. The default User works, but the API login don't.
This is my Student class:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


use App\Traits\FileValidator;

class Student extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens, FileValidator, Notifiable;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'cpf',
        'registration',
        'image',

        'classroom_id'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    const HAS_FOREIGN_KEYS = false;
    const HAS_FILE = true;
    public $file_field = "image";


    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

For more context, i though: "Ok, i'll just make the Student model like the User one, but with the default functions for a JWT authentication"

Then, reading how to make a JWT auth, it says to configure the guards, well, i want to make the application to check if the passed email and password matches a STUDENT email and password. So I made a eloquent provider using the Student model. Then used the "students" provider in a new "api" guard and passwords. Just like this:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider'=> 'students',
        ]
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'provider' => 'students',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Now I'll show my login method in the StudentController.php file

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'user' => $user,
            'authorisation' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ]);

    }
```

I have a student with the following: `{ email: 'teste3@teste.com', password: 'teste123' }`
Then I went to Insomnia to test the `localhost:8000/api/login` URL. I was expecting get the JWT Token, but it returned Unauthenticated. I wondered why, so I tested with the default user I have, in the desktop application. This default user have `{ email: 'admin@admin.com', password: 'admin123' }`, and **NONE OF THE STUDENTS HAVE THIS ENTRY**

Resuming. It still uses the Users table instead of the Students table. Even if I put the `Auth::shouldUse('api')` on the StudentController, it just returns nothing, like it has no student with the entry I pass.

If you guys need, This is my Users Model

```
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;

class User extends Authenticatable implements CanResetPassword
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    const HAS_FILE = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify((new ResetPassword($token)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Verify Configuration:**
   Ensure that the configuration in `config/auth.php` is correctly set. Make sure that you have `students` as the provider for the `api` guard.

   ```php
   'guards' => [
       'web' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],

       'api' => [
           'driver' => 'jwt',
           'provider' => 'students',
       ],
   ],
   ```

   Also, check the `providers` section to make sure that the `students` provider is correctly configured:

   ```php
   'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Models\User::class,
       ],

       'students' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
       ],
   ],
   ```
2. **Use Correct Guard:**
   Ensure that in your `StudentController.php`, you're using `Auth::guard('api')` to attempt authentication using the `api` guard.

   ```php
   $token = Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials);
   ```

   Also, ensure that you have `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` at the top of your `StudentController.php` file.
3. **Check Database Table:**
   Double-check that the `students` table exists and has the correct structure. Ensure that you have at least one student record in the `students` table with the provided email and password.
4. **Check Traits and Overrides:**
   Make sure that there are no conflicting traits or methods in your `Student` model that might interfere with the authentication process. Check if there are any overridden methods that could cause unexpected behavior.
5. **Clear Configuration Cache:**
   Sometimes configuration changes might not take effect immediately. Try clearing the configuration cache:

   ```bash
   php artisan config:clear
   ```

   Then try running your API login again.
6. **Verify Guard in Controller:**
   In your `StudentController.php`, make sure that you are using the correct guard using `Auth::guard('api')`:

   ```php
   $token = Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials);
   ```

   This ensures that the API guard is explicitly used for authentication.

If, after going through these steps, the issue persists, please provide additional details or any error messages you receive so that I can assist you further.